# How do I make this program start over from user's decision?

Tags: python

#### If the user inputs 'yes' I want the program to start over. If the user inputs 'no' I want it to end

```
def isValid(side1, side2, side3):
    if (((side1 + side2) > side3) 
        and ((side1 + side3) > side2) 
        and ((side2 + side3) > side1)):
            return True
    else:
        return False

def area(side1, side2, side3):
    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
    area = round(math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side3) * (s - side2)), 2)
    return area;

def main():
    side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ").split()
    side1 = eval(side1)
    side2 = eval(side2)
    side3 = eval(side3)

    valid = True

    valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)

    while True:
        if valid is not True:
            print("This is not a valid triangle.")
            print()
            print("Would you like to go again? ")
            answer = input()
        if answer == "yes" or "Yes":
            return True
        elif answer == "no" or "No":
            return False
        else:
            return
        break
    else:
        x = area(side1, side2, side3)
        print("The area of the triangle is ", x)

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    while True:
        side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ").split()
        side1 = eval(side1)
        side2 = eval(side2)
        side3 = eval(side3)

        valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)
        if not valid:
            print("This is not a valid triangle.")
            print()
            while True:
                print("Would you like to go again? (yes/no)")
                answer = input()
                if answer in ("no", "No"):
                    return
                elif answer in ("yes", "Yes"):
                    break
        else:
            x = area(side1, side2, side3)
            print("The area of the triangle is ", x)
            return
```

Comment: there is no need of two while loop and the break inside while loop only break one loop not the whole program

Comment: The inner while loop is used while user input neither yes nor no. At this position, we have to prompt him/her to input again

Comment: But what if he wanted to quit the function

Comment: He can just input "no", then main() will return, not break

Answer (score 0):

**Edit in your code:**

```
if answer == "yes" or answer=="Yes":
    return True
elif answer == "no" or answer=="No":
    return False
else:
    return
```

**My way:**

To reduce the typing

```
answer = input()
answer=answer.lower()
if answer == "yes" :
     return True
elif answer == "no":
     return False
else:
     return
```

**Modification:**

```
import math
def isValid(side1, side2, side3):
    if (((side1 + side2) > side3)  and ((side1 + side3) > side2) and ((side2 + side3) > side1)):
            return True
    else:
        return False

def area(side1, side2, side3):
    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
    area = round(math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side3) * (s - side2)), 2)
    return area;

def main():
    while True:
        side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ").split()
        side1 = int(side1)
        side2 = int(side2)
        side3 = int(side3)

        valid = True

        valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)


        if valid is not True:
            print("This is not a valid triangle.")
            print("\n")
            print("Would you like to go again? ")
            answer = input()
            answer=answer.lower()
            if answer == "yes" :
                continue
            elif answer == "no":
                break
            else:
                break
        else:
            x = area(side1, side2, side3)
            print("The area of the triangle is ", x)

main()
```

Comment: I tried running the program with the edits you suggested and it still doesn't start over.

Comment: There is logical error in your program wait will fix it and write

Comment: what version of python you are using

Comment: when I run the program it doesn't ask the user if they want to go again if they press yes; here is a sample: http://tinypic.com/r/359y654/8

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work.  Once you call `return True`, your program ends, and it looks like you want the loop to go on if the user said 'yes'.

```
def area():
    side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ").split() 
    side1 = eval(side1) 
    side2 = eval(side2) 
    side3 = eval(side3)
    valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)
    if valid:
        x = area(side1, side2, side3)
        print("The area of the triangle is ", x)
        return True
    else:
        print("This is not a valid triangle.\n")
        print("Would you like to go again? ")
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer == 'no':
            return False
        else:
            return area()
```

We can make it iterative instead of recursive, if we expect an evil nemesis to cause a stack overflow by giving your script an invalid triangle each time.

```
def area():
    side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ").split() 
    side1 = eval(side1) 
    side2 = eval(side2) 
    side3 = eval(side3)
    valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)
    if valid:
        x = area(side1, side2, side3)
        print("The area of the triangle is ", x)
        return True
    else:
        return False

while True:
    success = area()
    if success:
        return True
    else:
        print("This is not a valid triangle.\n")
        print("Would you like to go again? ")
        answer = input().lower()
        if answer == 'no':
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code works as required. The changes made are:

1. removed .split() when taking triangle lengths as input. instead of giving string, u can directly give list of lengths as [3,4,5]. it will automatically assign side1 = 3, side2 = 4, side3=5. hence removed side1=eval(side1) for all sides. input() takes input in the form u give it, unlike raw_input() which converts input to string.
2. brought complete code that needs to be repeated if answer is yes inside while loop.
3. answer = raw_input(); changed input() to raw_input() as we expect string here. so now don't need to write 'yes' with quotes at input, can simply write yes without quotes; it will still take it as string.
4. converted answer to 'lower', means all letters would be uncapitalized and then compared to 'yes' or 'no'
5. used flag for controlling while loop, instead of returning. when you use return, the function terminates and returns the value to like r in this case. But we don't want to end our function there, hence return should not used here.
6. inserted return x in else: block so that after printing, x is assigned to r also, if u want to use the value further. and hence replaced main() with r = main()

   ```
   def isValid(side1, side2, side3):
       if (((side1 + side2) > side3) and ((side1 + side3) > side2) and ((side2 + side3) > side1)):
           return True
       else:
           return False

   def area(side1, side2, side3):
       s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
       area = round(math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side3) * (s - side2)), 2)
       return area

   def main():
       flag = True
       while flag:
           side1, side2, side3 = input("Give me the lengths of a triangle's 3 sides?: ")

           valid = isValid(side1, side2, side3)
           if valid is not True:
               print("This is not a valid triangle.")
               print()
               print("Would you like to go again? ")
               answer = raw_input()
               if answer.lower() == "yes":
                   flag = True
               elif answer.lower() == "no":
                   flag = False

           else:
               x = area(side1, side2, side3)
               print("The area of the triangle is ", x)
               return x

       r = main()
   ```